# Why false != false?

Tags: c#

I have a method that check if 2 arguments are equal:

```
using System;

class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        CheckEquality(false, false);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void CheckEquality(object a, object b)
    {
        if (a == b){
            Console.WriteLine("yes");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, 2 arguments are "false", but when I run the program, the console says:

```
no
```

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are from reference class `Object`, operator== compares their address, not value.

Comment: Because you're not comparing values, you're comparing references to boxed objects containing Boolean values. The boolean values inside might be the same, but the `==` operator for `object` only compare references, and you have two distinct boxed objects, both containing `false` so the references are different.

Comment: You can try `if (a.Equals(b))` instead but beware that this does not handle `a` as a null reference.

Comment: Operators are not polymorphic, use if (a.Equals(b))

Answer (score 3):

You're actually not comparing values here.

You are comparing references. In this case references to object containing `bool` values.

So while the values inside the objects might be the same, the equals (`==`) operator for the object only compares the references, not the values. Since you have two distinct boxes the references are different, hence the result is `false`.